# Click Listener not working of CollapsingToolbarLayout child layout in android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working with CollapsingToolbarLayout and I have added include layout in CollapsingToolbarLayout tag. As below in XML.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Now in layout_header.xml have a parent relative layout that click is not working as below I had implemented.

```
RelativeLayout backPress    =    (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_backPress);
    backPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Can anyone know how to work on this... I had google a lot but nothing helped me in this issue.

Comment: I think you just not click on this layout because it overlays another layout. Try to apply background color android:background="#f00" on this relative layout and you will see it's real size (or not will see because of overlapping)

Comment: @Subzero If i apply any color on that relativeLayout it color appears